# a way to have django SITEURL constant in settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am from PHP background, and I know that constants can be accessed at most of places in a framework and I think it is same in django as well. I tried to have that URL too in django but I tried to have it from django.contrib. I tried to utilize django's Site class and imported that. But the problem is that at time of loading settings.py I can't import any django contrib. file.

So how can I have SITE URL automatically that I can use anywhere, in template as well as at other places.What is the best way to do so? Do any python utility can do so?

Comment: You probably just shouldn't place it in settings - it is Django way to have only id of current site in settings and access Site.objects.get_current() directly when needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whatever you define in your settings.py, for example

```
SITE_URL = 'http://www.mydomain.com'
```

Can be accessed in all your Django related code with:

```
from django.conf import settings #this imports also your specific settings.py

print settings.SITE_URL
```

Or just `Site.objects.get_current().domain`

If you want to be able to access it in the templates, you make your own [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). Put this in my_project/content_processor.py

```
from django.conf import settings
def my_site_url(request):
    return {
        'SITE_URL': settings.SITE_URL,
    }
```

Or if you want it Dynamic:

```
from django.conf import settings
def my_site_url(request):
    return {
        'SITE_URL': Site.objects.get_current().domain,
    }
```

And add it to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS variable in settings.py. It should look similar to that afterwards:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS =("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"my_project.context_processors.my_site_url",
)
```

and finished.

Comment: Plus one to detail provided by your but problem is that I want to minimize the hardcoded settings, I want this SITE_URL in settings.py to be dynamic like `Site.objects.get_current().domain` get the URL dynamically, as I don't see any sort of helpers in django like if I set them somewhere and then access it everywhere, may be if there is something like helpers then I can access Site class of django too.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether you can make values in the settings dynamically from a model. But I updated my answer.