# How to make Django Server URL config-driven instead of being hard-coded?

Tags: django

I am using Django with React, each time I have to use React to get the data from the database I have to do something like this:

```
var URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/api/games/'
var API_URL = URL + '?term=' + this.props.token
await axios.get(API_URL)
   .then(res => {
       temp = res.data
})
```

How can I avoid hardcoding "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" like this and set up it in the setting.py? Can someone show me how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12333836/6817428

Comment: setting.py means the server, how can the React reach the server before knowing its address?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this only needs to be changed in the React app and not in the `settings.py` of Django.

Take the URL of wherever you deploy your Django application (in development this could be locally at `127.0.0.1:8000` but in Production this will most likely be something like `api.example.com`) and this will become an Environment Variable injected at build time of your React app.

Generally you will have a `.env` configuration file per environment (`DEV`/`TEST`/`PROD` etc.) which will contain all variables that can then be used in your code.

Check out [Using environment variables in React](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5) for a detailed post on why you would use environment variables and how to use them in your Javascript applications.