# getting the full path of an url from django (not django template)

Tags: django, path, django-templates

I'm a bit lost on getting the full path of an url from django. From questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15520246/5176549) i should be able to get the path using `get_current_site`, but it seems it is not supported anymore.

In specificts I have the following `urls.py`:

```
app_name = "core"
urlpatterns = [
    path("<str:model_string>/", tables_views.table_from_model, name="table_from_model"),
```

With django template it would be easy to acces it: `{% url 'core:table_from_model' mymodel %}`
However i need to acces from a python script.
I can of course just write something like: `http://127.0.0.1:8001/alert/` but then, the moment I go live, this method would fail (the url would not anymore be 127...).

Is that solvable?

Thanks

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12333836/2613005